# Accessing specific property of a cell of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a cell class as

```
public class cell {
private boolean pointerIsHere;
private boolean hurdle;
private boolean startCell;
private boolean endCell;}
```

now i made a double ArrayList of this cell type in another class `grid`.
the initialization of this ArrayList is;

```
gameGrid(int rows,int columns){
    this.rows=rows;
    this.columns=columns;
    this.grid=new ArrayList<List<cell>>(this.rows);

    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++) {
        this.grid.add(new ArrayList<cell>(this.columns));
    }
}
```

In a method of class `grid`, I need to set `startCell` as `true` of a specific cell of ArrayList. How am I supposed to access that specific cell and its property?

Comment: Write a setter.

Comment: What is a double ArrayList?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i did. in `cell` class. the problem is to access a specific cell's setter in double arrayList.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee its a 2d arrayList of type `cell`

Comment: could you please write a code via which you are initializing `double ArrayList`

Comment: @NileshDeokar please see updated question

Comment: i dont understand why people downvote questions here

Comment: @AghaKhan Please place your mouse over the downvote button, wait a few seconds and read the text that shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the field is private, you would have to implement getter/setter methods. Then you use the nested lists' get():

```
public class cell {
    // ...
    public void setStartCell(boolean start) {
        this.startCell = start;
    }
}
```

And for accessing the setter of the cell in the list:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> l = new ArrayList<>();
// list filling
l.get(row).get(col).setStartCell(true);
```

Comment: phew. that was easy